# Count repetitions Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a file like this:

```
CONTOSO-A\AAA
CONTOSO-B\BBB
CONTOSO-B\CCC
CONTOSO-A\AAA
....
....
```

How can count each line to get:

```
CONTOSO-A\AAA - 2 
CONTOSO-B\BBB - 1
CONTOSO-B\CCC - 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a hash table:

```
$counts = @{}

Get-Content c:\somedir\somefile.txt |
 foreach { $counts[$_]++ }

$counts

Name                           Value                                                             
----                           -----                                                             
CONTOSO-A\AAA                  2                                                                 
CONTOSO-B\CCC                  1                                                                 
CONTOSO-B\BBB                  1
```

Comment: Thank you @mjolinor ! Works perfect, Could I show only greater than 2?

Comment: Your welcome!  Yes, you can show only > 2 like this: $counts.GetEnumerator() | where {$_.value -gt 2} . It's not much different than using an object, you just have to use the .getenumerator() method on the hash table.  The group-object solutions posted will work too.  I tend to prefer the hash table method for file data because it seems to scale better if it gets a really large file thrown at it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-Content .\file.txt | Group-Object | Select-Object name, count
```

Comment: You could stick a `|ft -a` on the end as well.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is probably:

```
PS C:\temp> @"
CONTOSO-A\AAA
CONTOSO-B\BBB
CONTOSO-B\CCC
CONTOSO-A\AAA
"@ | set-content test.txt

get-content test.txt | group -NoElement

Count Name                     
----- ----                     
    2 CONTOSO-A\AAA            
    1 CONTOSO-B\BBB            
    1 CONTOSO-B\CCC
```

Using the `-NoElement` option to `group` or `Group-Object` means you don't have to do a separate `select` to extract just name and count.

To get the exact format you asked for:

```
PS C:\temp> get-content test.txt | group -NoElement | % { $_.Name +" - "+$_.Count }
CONTOSO-A\AAA - 2
CONTOSO-B\BBB - 1
CONTOSO-B\CCC - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stat = @{};
cat file.txt | % { $stat["$_"] = $stat["$_"] + 1; }
$stat;
```